# Call AsyncTask in the onRecive

Tags: android, android-asynctask, widget

I need to call  `AsyncTask` function since the `onReceive()`. The problem is when I call the function, the different  `TextViews` it must change in the `onPostExecute()`, don't change it!

**This is the code:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);


            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, widget.class);

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView56, "ACTUALIZANDO"); 
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            new LongOperation(views, appWidgetId, appWidgetManager).execute("MyTestString"); //Calling the asyncTask

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
```

And the `AsyncTask`. This part of the code we use and also works when I call sice the `onUpdate`:

```
public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private RemoteViews views;
        private int WidgetID;
        private AppWidgetManager WidgetManager;

        public LongOperation(RemoteViews views, int appWidgetID, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager){
            this.views = views;
            this.WidgetID = appWidgetID;
            this.WidgetManager = appWidgetManager;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                ....
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ....
            }

            return temperatura;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView66, result+ "ºC ");

            WidgetManager.updateAppWidget(WidgetID, views);
        }
    }
```

I think that the problem is in the `appWidgetId` but I can't solve...

Thanks,

MArc

Comment: The use of `AsyncTask` in `BroadCast` is bad practice, because Android may kill your process onReceive if there is no any active `Service` or `Activity`, and no gurantee its return.

Comment: Hmmm... so we need to create a Service to do this asyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `AsyncTask` in `BroadCast` is bad practice, because Android may kill your process in `onReceive()` if there is no any active `Service` or `Activity`, and no gurantee its return.

In this case, [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding) recommends [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> "The specific constraint on BroadcastReceiver execution time
>   emphasizes what broadcast receivers are meant to do: small, discrete
>   amounts of work in the background such as saving a setting or
>   registering a Notification. So as with other methods called in the UI
>   thread, applications should avoid potentially long-running operations
>   or calculations in a broadcast receiver. But instead of doing
>   intensive tasks via worker threads, your application should start an
>   IntentService if a potentially long running action needs to be taken
>   in response to an intent broadcast."